# How to pass data from a view to a controller's post endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am able to view data from the database via a ViewModel like this:

```
[HttpGet] 
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Rent(int id)
{
    Helper helper = new Helper();

    var cars = _context.Cars.Find(id);
    var useremail = User.Identity.Name;
    var username = helper.GetName(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var viewmodel = new RentalViewModel
    {
        UserName = username,
        UserEmail = useremail,
        CarMake = cars.Make,
        CarMod = cars.Mod,
        CarPicture = cars.Picture,
        CarPrice = cars.Price,
        CarId = cars.Id
    };

    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

This is working great in the view and i am able to call the data i need in it.

Now what i'm trying to do is to press a button, and then execute an HttpPost method that will take this data and save it in a table (Model) called Rental.

This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RentPost(RentalViewModel model)
{
    var rentals = new Rental
    {
        CarId = model.CarId
    };

    _context.Rentals.Add(rentals);

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
}
```

and this is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RentPost", "Home", new {id = @Model.CarId}))
{
    <h1> @Model.UserName </h1>
    <h1> @Model.UserEmail </h1>
    <h1> @Model.CarMake @Model.CarMod </h1>
    <h1>  </h1>
    <img src="@Model.CarPicture" alt="" />
    <h1> {@Model.CarPrice*3} </h1>

    @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.CarId)

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>
}
```

I am only passing one element for now just for testing purposes and redirecting also for the same reason. Upon debugging this, CarId is NULL and that is understandable because the ViewModel is empty at this point of execution. Can anybody direct me toward the correct implementation? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-hidden-hiddenfor . In short - for the data to get from the view (web browser) to the server there needs to be a field in the form being posted. `Html.HiddenFor` is used for stuff you don't want to be edited (e.g. IDs). `Html.TextBoxFor` is used for stuff you *do* want to be edited.

Comment: Not seeing any inputs that would send data back to controller.

Comment: oh my god i am so stupid! I thought i typed hiddenfor but for some reason it was displayfor. Thanks alot guys, feel free to delete the question if its too stupid

Comment: You aren't stupid. Everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for help. Is there a better way to pass the data? I feel having a form (@html.beginform) is kinda redundant because im only posting hidden data and nothing else

Comment: Not true, use ajax for a better user experience. Posting forms via submit buttons is so 2012.

Comment: I've actually implemented something similar using jquery Ajax, it's just I'm trying to publish this project on github and trying to show my skills in asp.net but thanks for the tip :)